# How do I configure rsyslog to send logs from a specific program to a remote syslog server?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have a program which outputs to syslog with a given tag/program name. I'd like to be able to filter syslog traffic from that program and send it to a remote syslog server, leaving all other syslog traffic local.

I can send all traffic to the remote server with

```
*.* @remote_server
```

How do I filter it?

Comment: This answered my question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042115/ruby-syslog-custom-facility

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Rsyslog config files are located in: `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`

Rsyslog reads the conf files sequentially, so it is important that you name your config file so that the specific config is loaded before anything else happens. So, name your file starting with leading zero's, i.e. `00-my-file.conf`. It's better to create a new file so that updates and so on doesn't overwrite your local config.

Example:

```
if $programname == 'programname' and $msg contains 'a text string' and $syslogseverity <= '6' then /var/log/custom/bind.log
```

Or if you just want to discard certain entries:

```
if $programname == 'programname' then ~
```

**In your case: (UDP)**

```
if $programname == 'programname' then @remote.syslog.server
& ~
```

**Or (TCP)**

```
if $programname == 'programname' then @@remote.syslog.server
& ~
```

The `& ~` means to stop processing matching (previous line only!) entries further.

**Some more general info:**

Also, always make sure filters are on the same line:

```
# Example: Log mail server control messages to mail-queue.log
if $hostname == 'titus'\
and $programname == 'smtp.queue.'\
and $syslogseverity <= '6' then /var/log/titus/mail-queue.log
& ~
```

Usefull filters:

```
$hostname
$programname
$msg
$syslogseverity
```

Operators:

```
== (equals)
contains
and
or
```

More info: http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Configuration_Samples

Comment: can we fix the broken link?

Comment: the `$msg` is still written to `syslog` as well as `/var/log/custom.log`.  How to output only to `custom.log`?

Answer (score 1):

We can also try this. It's working fine for me.

```
$template Incoming-logs,"/var/log/testing_docker/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
if $programname startswith 'docker' then -?Incoming-logs
```

NOTE: here `testing_docker` folder ownership should be given to the syslog user. Follow the below command to set permissions.

```
chown syslog:syslog testing_docker
```