# rsyslog isolation to avoid system and app mix

Tags: rsyslog

I am passing my IIS app logs (log4net) files to rsyslog (`/var/log/syslog`) in my Ubuntu server.

I want to preserve a special place for these logs and I don't want them to be mixed with other services writing to the rsyslog. 
What are the alternatives here?

Should I create a special file? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/186642/158442 (the examples include one for writing to a separate file)